# Working with web services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm developing an .NET application (WinForms, .NET Framework 4.0) and i need to call a method from a web service.

The problem is that the client's web service is only accessible from inside its network. So at development time, i can't access it, so I can add it as a refference.

How should I proceed?

Should I create some kind of replica of that web service in my network?
Which would be the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd get the WSDL and write a mock of it that i can call from my side.

I'd then make it return data that i was expecting and then later on have it return data that i wasn't expecting.

Then when you deploy it (should) be ok but you would need to run some integration tests.

The alternative it to tell them to open a port for you to use so that you can write the s/ware.

Comment: Thank you! could you please provide some more details ?

Answer (score 0):

You could replicate the web service which returns dummy data.

Comment: @maephisto, same WSDL, dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the call to the service in a separate abstraction layer, this would allow you to provide a different implementation if you wish during testing.

Eg. Something along the lines of..

```
public interface IXYZServiceInvoker
{
   SomeData SomeServiceCall();
}    

public class SomeServiceInvoker : IXYZServiceInvoker
{
   public void SomeServiceCall()
   {
             //Calls a real service    
   }        
}    

public class FakeServiceInvoker : IXYZServiceInvoker
{
    public SomeData SomeServiceCall()
    {
             //returns some dummy/test data    
    } 
}
```